# Прочитать всю очередь. FreeRTOS

Tags: очередь, esp32, freertos

у меня есть небольшое приложение для ESP32 с использованием FreeRTOS. В приложении есть очередь на 7 элементов, которая формируется из сигналов от внешнего считывателя, основная таска разгребает эту очередь и выполняет соответствующие действия, но появилась необходимость проверять очередь на наличие дублей. xQueuePeek, как я понимаю, взаимодействует только с первым элементом очереди и пробежаться им по всей очереди никак нельзя, какой-то готовой функции, как я понял, тоже нет. Так вот, какие оптимальные варианты можно применить в данном случае?